# FusionCharts Failed to draw different chart on same data source

Tags: angular, charts, highcharts, fusioncharts

My requirement is to draw charts dynamically based on web-services response that is `chartType` and the specific formated `dataSet` but FusionChart failed to do that.

In below example, Let's suppose dataSet format is same for all the charts types like (line, column, stacked etc.) but when i change the chart type it display **No Data Available**

*Note : Same thing i have achieved in HighCharts but my client is forced us to use fusion charts

```
export const getChartOptions = (chartOptions) => {
    return {
        chartConfig: {
            type: chartOptions.type,
            dataFormat: chartOptions.dataFormat,
        },
        dataSource: {
            chart: {
                caption: chartOptions.caption,
                subCaption: chartOptions.subCaption,
                xAxisName: chartOptions.xAxisName,
                yAxisName: chartOptions.yAxisName,
                numberSuffix: chartOptions.numberSuffix,
                theme: chartOptions.theme,
                showLegend: '1'
            },
            categories: [
                {
                    category: [{
                        label: 'Q1'
                    }, {
                        label: 'Q2'
                    }, {
                        label: 'Q3'
                    }, {
                        label: 'Q4'
                    }]
                }
            ],
            dataset: [{
                seriesname: 'Last Year',
                data: [{
                    value: 10000
                }, {
                    value: 11500
                }, {
                    value: 12500
                }, {
                    value: 15000
                }]
            }]
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FusionCharts has got some prescribed data format for single and multi-series charts, for the single series chart you need have data as like this `data:[{label:"mylabel"},{value:123}]`

Similarly, for multi-series charts, you need to have categories object which will hold the x-axis labels and the dataset object that holds multiple data objects for each series

Tip: If you want to draw a column/line plot with the existing dataSource set the chart type as mscolumn2d OR msline

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'mscolumn2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      chart: {

        showLegend: '1'
      },
      categories: [{
        category: [{
          label: 'Q1'
        }, {
          label: 'Q2'
        }, {
          label: 'Q3'
        }, {
          label: 'Q4'
        }]
      }],
      dataset: [{
        seriesname: 'Last Year',
        data: [{
          value: 10000
        }, {
          value: 11500
        }, {
          value: 12500
        }, {
          value: 15000
        }]
      }]
    }
  }).render();
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/tz0orfkq/

Comment: thanks for your answer but my requirement is to draw charts dynamically based on chart type provided by backend api, for the above given example when I change the chart type line, bar2d etc. it doesn't show any data  as you can check in your above appended JSFiddle

Comment: please read my above statement properly, if you want to render the chart based on the above datasource set the chart type as msbar2d, msline instead of line and bar2d